# Making more than 4 vertices in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Just wanted to know how I can make a div with more vertices just like the picture below:
[image]

Is there any way to do that with css or JavaScript?
What I wanted to do is to add a text inside this orange shape, so the image that is on the top left area doesn't overlay the text.

Comment: Couldn't you just put the image inside the div, and the text will wrap around it?  The answer to can you make a div like that is no.

Comment: Tom, actually no. I am using this in wordpress, and since it is a responsive website and all that stuff it would be a nightmare make that clean, also, I just prefer to keep my css clean and easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could fake it. I'm not sure how much of that image is required, but I recreated it identically using a masking `<div>` with absolute positioning in order to keep the border looking the way you have it. This is actually a nested div with a bottom and right border overlapping (at the top and left) a div with all four borders set.

You can see the [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/na755dbw/)

**To answer your question**

No, you can't make a polygonal `div` but you can fake one if you would like.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="mask">
           Image here
        </div>
        <div id="image">

        </div>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        <br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#mask{
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 8px;
    left: 8px;
    background-color: white;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    z-index: 1;
}

#container{
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: orange;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid black;
}

#image{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Well, the border wasn't really necessary, by that illustration I just wanted to show what the shape is like, but thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done.  I recreated your example, including the black outline (although I don't know how important the border was).  You will need to use a float element to control the text, but you can absolutely clip the div tag however you'd like using clip-path.  I'm pasting the code below, but you can play with the jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/4mjnuxpv/

Sample HTML

```
<div class="background">
<div class="clipped">
  <div class="boundary"></div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris 
  augue nulla, sagittis vitae leo in, pulvinar pulvinar nisi. 
  Proin quis dolor efficitur, sodales lectus eget, posuere risus. 
  Phasellus eleifend iaculis leo in efficitur. Sed lacus dui, 
  consectetur id malesuada quis, feugiat eu arcu. Sed justo magna, 
  luctus id pellentesque vel, tristique quis leo. Sed vel est id 
  orci fringilla efficitur. Morbi eleifend aliquam risus, nec 
  ullamcorper tortor cursus vel. Fusce in ante felis. Praesent 
  vehicula ante ac luctus iaculis. Aenean sed felis vitae elit 
  feugiat feugiat.
</div>
</div>
```

And the accompanying style (background is the black border, clipped is the orange area, and boundary is the invisible div that controls the text flow.  Feel free to set the width and height of `background` to any size you'd like, and the orange will fill it.:

```
.background {
  width: 200px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  clip-path: polygon(0 100px, 100px 100px,
    100px 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 50px);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 100px, 100px 100px,
    100px 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 50px);
}

.clipped {
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; 
  background-color: orange;
  clip-path: polygon(2px 102px, 102px 102px, 
    102px 0, calc(100% - 2px) 0, 
    calc(100% - 2px) calc(100% - 2px), 
    0 calc(100% - 2px),
    0 52px);
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(2px 102px, 102px 102px, 
    102px 2px, calc(100% - 2px) 2px, 
    calc(100% - 2px) calc(100% - 2px), 
    2px calc(100% - 2px),
    2px 52px);
}

.boundary {
  height: 100px;
  width: 105px;
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something in the manner below where you can float the image on the top left.

```
      <html>
      <body>
      <div style="height: 60px;width: 60px;background-color: white;margin: 0px;float: left; border-          right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black">
      </div>
      <div style="height: 200px;background-color: orange; border: 1px solid black;width: 200px;">
      THis is awesome. THis is awesome. THis is awesome.THis is awesome. THis is awesome. THis is awesome. THis is awesome. THis is awesome.
      </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the image inside a div and apply float:left css setting on it.

```
 <div style="float:left;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:5px;">
    <img src="image_url" />
</div>
text text text
```

The text will be wrapped around the image.

**Demo here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/uu2mmbtj/